# Best way to describe the script dependencies in a Ruby Gem - where should I require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to the Ruby world and started building my first Ruby gem.

I noticed that require is quite different than what I expected. Let say I have the following scripts in my gem

```
-  My Gem
  -  lib
       script-1.rb
       script-2.rb
       script-3.rb
       ...
       main.rb
  + bin
  + exe
  ...
```

In the exe I cal the main.rb - the main entry point for my gem.

It uses a class from script-1.rb to do it's job work.
script-1.rb on it behalf depends on code script-2.rb. And so on.

Here is my question.

Where is the best place to `require` the scripts. Mainly from maintainability point of view. Let's say that during the lifetime of my executable all of the scripts will be loaded anyway. I see 2 options:

1. `require` all of the scripts for my app in main.rb
2. Each script does `require` only for the scripts it depends on.
3. Introduce a new boot script

I started using option 2. But soon enough I understand that require does a global modification and some of the scripts are missing `require` since some other script already did this.

So what is the best practice here. I would rather create a separate script for initialisation - like defining the dependencies of my gem, but I was wondering if there is a better approach I am missing? How do you describe the decencies between scripts in your gems?

Comment: Can the scripts be used independently? If so then (IMO) they should should require just what they need. If not then formally requiring them upfront would clean things up a bit I guess. There is really no harm in "requiring" something twice as the second time it will just return `false` since it has already been required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your gem doesn't work with [Bundler](https://bundler.io) out of the box by declaring:

```
gem 'mygem'
```

Then you've got to explain in the documentation why. Some gems, for intractable technical reasons, require you to load in specific files, or recommend that for some occasions. Bundler itself is one such gem:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

Where that will not only load Bundler, but will initiate the Bundler environment setup and imports the `Gemfile` settings.

Normally your gem should have a main library file with the same name as the gem itself, and that takes care of loading all dependencies.

For example, `mygem` looks like:

```
mygem.rb
mygem/some_module.rb
mygem/other_module.rb
```

Where the main `mygem` looks like:

```
module MyGem
  # ...
end

require_relative './mygem/some_module'
require_relative './mygem/other_module'
```

The `require` calls are ordered so that any dependencies are properly accounted for.

If you have a module that has other dependencies of its own, the pattern repeats, like in `mygem/submodule.rb`:

```
module MyGem::Submodule
  # ...
end

require_relative './submodule/something'
```